# How to show all products category wise in shopping cart summary page in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop

I want to show all the products in prestashop in my cart summary page.

Even though the customer doesn't ordered a product, it should be displayed in his/her shopping cart summary page with quantity as 0. So that from there he must be able to add quantity if he needs.

The product must be displayed category wise.

NB: I have searched and couldn't find a solution :-(

Comment: Any code would be helpful...

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should not use cart, but should use template for product category instead of cart. This template make you able to show cart quantity. Cart will "invisible" in your shop. The user will select quantity of goods, all of them will add to the cart on 'onchange' event. When, the user press "Order" button and go to the real cart where he see the summary order information and confirm his order. Shop without traditional cart will inconvenient, because selected goods will in the different categories of the shop

The result will like this: http://screencast.com/t/8csYCudqD
Use ajax command which using on 'Add to cart' button click on 'onChange' event for input with good's count (simple jquery ajax)